# How to Use Qt Application to Install and Uninstall Win Service

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2017

I have a windows service and Qt C++ UI. I want to install Winservice whenever my QT UI starts and uninstall the Winservice when I close the UI. How can I do it?

I already tried QProcess, but it did not work. I tried to call winservice.bat as well as winservice.exe, but both times QProcess not able to run.

```
    QString sFile = "install.bat ";
    Process process;
    process.start(sFile);
```

Comment: Do you want to install/uninstall or start/stop the service?

Comment: I wanted to install and start win service when my application begins and I wanted to stop and uninstall win service when I close the application.